# styled-components conditional props doesn't work in Material-ui components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'd like to set fade-in, fade-out animation on the Grid component using Material-UI and styled-components. But it doesn't work and there is an error about the conditional prop. Could you tell me how to do that, please?

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { keyframes } from "styled-components";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

const fadeIn = keyframes`
  0% {
    height: 0
  }
  50% {
    height: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
`;

const fadeOut = keyframes`
  0% {
    height: 100%
  }
  50% {
    height: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0;
  }
`;


const AnimationGrid = styled(Grid)<{ isOpen: boolean }>`
  && {
    visibility: ${props => (props.isOpen ? "visible" : "hidden")};
    animation: ${props => (props.isOpen ? fadeIn : fadeOut)}
      0.3s linear 0s 1 forwards;
  }
`;


type AnimationProps = {
  isOpen: boolean;
};


const AnimationComp = ({isOpen}: AnimationProps) => {
  return (
        <AnimationGrid container isOpen={isOpen}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
              Here is left section 
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
              Here is right section
          </Grid>
        </AnimationGrid>
  )
}
```

Also there is a error on console. Fade-in animation is fine but fade-out doesn't work.

```
Warning: React does not recognize the `isOpen` prop on a DOM element. 
If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, 
spell it as lowercase `isopen` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, 
remove it from the DOM element.
```

I'd say isOpen prop doesn't work well. Thank you.

Comment: official document about [style hooks](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/)

Answer (score 2):

Your question consists of 2 parts, so I'll answer it that way.

For the console error: this behavior has been bugging many people. The reason you see this error, is because the property `isOpen` is passed to the underlying DOM element. However, DOM elements don't support a boolean attribute `isOpen`.
To work around this, you can use

```
styled(({ isOpen, ...props }) => <Grid {...props} />)<{ isOpen: boolean }>`...`
```

For the animation part: you don't see the fade-out animation, because you set `visibility: hidden` at the start of it. This way, the element disappears immediately. To get similar behavior to `visibility: hidden`,
you could add `opacity: 0` to your animation at '100%'
and set `pointer-events: ${props => props.isOpen ? 'initial' : 'none'}`.

Hope this helps!